# How to connect an existing SQL Server login to an existing SQL Server database user of same name

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a SQL Server command to connect a **user** of a single database to a **login** for the database server of the same name?

For example:

> Database Server - Default Instance
>   Database: TestDB
>
> Server Login - TestUser
>   Existing user on TestDB - TestUser

If I try to make the `TestUser` login a user of the `TestDB` database, the "User, group, or role" already exists.

Does anybody know of an easy way to assign the DB **user** to the server **login**?

Answer (score 303, accepted):

The *new* way (SQL 2008 onwards) is to use [ALTER USER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176060.aspx)

```
ALTER USER OrphanUser WITH LOGIN = correctedLoginName;
```

Comment: Since SQL Server 2005. Gratzy's link refers to this actually.

Comment: I just used this in SQL Server 2012 and I can confirm it works

Comment: Confirmed as still working on SQL Server 2019.

Comment: And confirmed in SQL Server 2022

Answer (score 7):

I think it's [`sp_change_users_login`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174378.aspx). It's been a little while, but I used to do that when detaching and reattaching databases.

Comment: If the SQL login was created using a Windows user login, then sp_change_users_login will not work--I ran into this today, leading me to this question. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174378.aspx

Comment: this method is deprecated now in favour of the [`ALTER USER` method, above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3144472/542251)

Comment: @liam did you really just down vote this answer that is 8 years old and reference the accepted answer that is also 8 years old which already contains the information that its deprecated?

Answer (score 1):

I've used the `sp_change_users_login` procedure to accomplish, I think, that scenario.