# SQL map a login to an existing user

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have recently upgraded my development environment from SQL 2000 to SQL 2008 R2.  I've done a backup of our production db and restored it our new dev server.

I have created  a login on the dev server which mirrors the login I use on the production server, but I can't get it mapped to the 'dbo' user in the database.  When I edit the properties of the login in 'User Mapping",  I replace the user with 'dbo',  and I get the following error:

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Create failed for User
>   'dbo'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo) An exception occurred while
>   executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo) User, group, or role 'dbo'
>   already exists in the current database. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error:
>   15023)

So how do I map a login to an existing user?

Comment: There is [Alter user](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176060.aspx) command: `alter user xyz with login = [domain\username]`

Comment: Delete and recreate the user

Comment: If the answer that I provided was sufficient to solve your problem, would you mind marking it as the correct solution? Here is a link to meta with more information. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/256426

Comment: ALTER USER [username] WITH LOGIN = [username]

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144380/how-to-connect-an-existing-sql-server-login-to-an-existing-sql-server-database-u

Comment: The issue encountered is primarily that the "User Mapping" tab is coded so that it tries to *create* the specified user in the DB (who already exists), thus the error. I haven't found a solution via SSMS, so the T-SQL way seems to be the only way for now.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To reconcile the the user with the login, you can used the system stored procedure sp_change_users_login.

```
sp_change_users_login [ @Action = ] 'action'
[ , [ @UserNamePattern = ] 'user' ] 
[ , [ @LoginName = ] 'login' ] 
[ , [ @Password = ] 'password' ];
```

For example:

`EXEC sp_change_users_login 'Update_One','User123','User123'`

If you have a lot of users who are out of sync, you can use a cursor to pull out all of the users and run this command for them. There isn't any adverse effect to running this against users that aren't out of sync, and it will fix all of the orphaned users.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE curSQL CURSOR
FOR
       SELECT   'EXEC sp_change_users_login ''UPDATE_ONE'', ''' + name + ''', ''' + name + ''''
       FROM     sysusers
       WHERE    issqluser = 1
                AND name NOT IN ( 'guest', 'dbo', 'sys', 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA' )
OPEN curSQL
FETCH curSQL INTO @sql
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
     BEGIN
           EXEC (
           @sql
           )
           FETCH curSQL INTO @sql
     END
CLOSE curSQL
DEALLOCATE curSQL
```

This has to be run of the context of the database you need the users fixed in.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is the result of having users who have SID's that are out of sync. I've experienced this issue when restoring  a database to a new server where I created a login that is named the same as the original server, but the SID that gets generated will be different, so SQL Server can't reconcile the user to it's login. There is a component in Integration Services capable of fixing this issue permanently, but learn from my heartache, it disables the user and overwrites the password.

Comment: When I run your query I get: Must declare the scalar variable "@sql".

Comment: I can't believe this has gone this long without that being caught. Sorry about that. It just needs that variable to be declared. I added it to the script.

Answer (score 32):

I think Nikola Markovinović's comment to this post needs to be added as an answer. Use the Alter user command:

```
USE {database}; 
ALTER USER {user} WITH login = {login}
```

Where:

- {database}: The database containing the orphan user
- {user}: The orphan user name
- {login}: The login name. You can use the same login as used on the old server or map the user to a different login name

I found this answer at http://www.aip.im/2010/05/re-map-database-user-to-login-in-sql-server-after-restoring-or-attaching-database/#sthash.fbazv94Z.dpuf

Answer (score 1):

Under SQL Server 2012, the user 'dbo' cannot be altered.

Comment: **dbo** is a _schema_, not a _user_.

Comment: @Suncat2000 but if you try to map a login to "dbo", it will tell you that such a *user* already exists. Even if it just told you "Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal "dbo" does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15517)"