# How to connect to a local SQL Server using ODBC data connections? (rn I get "login failed")

Tags: sql-server, odbc, dsn

I have to migrate some old web sites to a new server. On the old server, one web site was connected via an ODBC data source connection to another server where its database was running.

Right now I backed-up said database, restored it on my new server and now I'm trying to configure the new ODBC data source connection. Connecting to the old server via IP-address, then using my admin login + PW works fine.

Now how do I connect to my local machine's local SQL Server database? Normally it should just be, change the target IP to my server name right (the server I want to connect to)? Then when I use my admin login + PW, I get an error:

> Login failed for user {myadminuser}

Why is this? Backing up & restoring the database should keep the users intact right? Then why can't I connect to my restored local database using the same user & PW??

Comment: mhm I see, I could make a connection using Windows Authentication because that's what I use to connect to my local object explorer in SQL server management studio. How can I use the ODBC data source connection again with SQL users? So that I can use those logins again?

Answer (score 0):

Security in SQL Server is a two-level process:

- you have **logins** which are at the **server level** (and thus **NOT** backed up with a database)
- and each database then contains **users** that are connected to these logins.

If you backup & restore a database onto a new server, you have the **users** in the database - but those are **NO LONGER** connected to the **logins** on that new SQL Server instance.

So when you move a database to a new server, you **must also** make sure those **logins** at the server level are again made available, and connected to the database's users

Comment: mhm I see, I could make a connection using Windows Authentication because that's what I use to connect to my local object explorer in SQL server management studio. How can I use the ODBC data source connection again with SQL users? So that I can use those logins again?

Comment: @Tempuslight: read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/troubleshoot-orphaned-users-sql-server and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144380/how-to-connect-an-existing-sql-server-login-to-an-existing-sql-server-database-u